# Trying to serve a React app with Flask backend, but getting 403 error

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, web

I'm trying to serve a React app with a flask API as a backend. I've followed some tutorial online, where they suggest using the 'proxy' field in the package.json of the React app, created using the create-react-app function. However, when I call the following function from within React,

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/foo').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
      setCurrentTime(data.field);
    });
  }, []);
```

where in Flask I'm serving,

```py
@app.route('/foo')
def get_current_time():
    return {'field': 'foo'}
```

The error I'm getting in the console is:

```
App.js:9          GET http://localhost:3000/foo 403 (Forbidden)

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

I'm not experienced in web dev to debug this.

Comment: Do you get cors error?

Comment: Change ```return {'field': 'foo'}``` to ```return json.dumps({'field': 'foo'})```

Comment: In the real code, the the endpoint name is different to what I've shown here. When I changed the endpoint name to something random and tested it, it started work for some reason. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Im not a pro flask developer but i think i may experienced the same situation.

The client (react app) seems to wait for a proper kind of 'REST response' (not 100% sur that is a REST rule question but anyway).
I recommend you to try to return that flask' get_current_time() method with this object structure :

```
{"status": 200, "message": "success", "data":{{'field': 'foo'}}
```

PS : Did you try to rename get_current_time() to get() ?

Answer (score 0):

On macos change the proxy in `package.json` to `"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000"`

Source: [*How To Create a React + Flask Project*](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-create-a-react--flask-project/page/6#comments)